# Get Fetched Data to table data in material ui react

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I Have Fetched Some Data from a url via axios .I want to display those data to material ui table data in React. Here, 'patient' is the array where fetched data stored. 
Code:

```
const [patient, setPatient] = React.useState([])
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
columns: [
  { title: 'Name', field: 'name' },
  { title: 'Gender', field: 'gender' },
  { title: 'Age', field: 'age', type : 'numeric' },
  { title: 'Birth Year', field: 'birthYear', type : 'numeric' },
  { title: 'Phone Number', field: 'phoneNumber', type : 'tele'  
  },
  ],
  data: [
  ],
 });

 React.useEffect(()=>{
 axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/patient/AppModel/')
 .then(res =>{
  setPatient(res.data)
 })
.catch(err=>{
  console.log(err)
})
 },[])

return (
 <MaterialTable
  title="Patient List"
  columns={state.columns}
  data={state.data}
    />
 })}
```

But actually i don't how to get an array data to an array of objects.